# Return a list of (x,y) coordinates in excel to matrix form

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have an excel file with 2 columns represent for X and Y coordinates and I want to transform them to the matrix format such as: [X1,Y1], [X2,Y2],....How could I do this?
Thank you very much

[image: Screenshot table & matrix format]

I tried VBA excel and python but i dont know how to do this.

Comment: What attempt have you made so far, and what specific problem did you run into getting it to work?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel vba, you could use a UDF:

```
Function create_matrix(rng As Range) As String
    Dim rw As Range, element As Range
    output = "["
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        For Each element In rw.Cells
            output = output & element.Value & ", "
        Next
        output = Left(output, Len(output) - 2) & "], ["
    Next
    create_matrix = Left(output, Len(output) - 3)
End Function
```

Here is what that looks like in action:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

(1) you can use excel formulas to solve this task:

D2: = "[" & A2 & ", " & B2 & "]"
copy to last cell in column D

E2: = D2
E3: = E2 & ", " & D3
copy to last cell in column E

(2) use vba

```
Function create_matrix_format(myRange As Range) As String
Dim firstCell As Boolean
Dim nextLineStr As String
Dim resultStr As String
    firstCell = True
    For Each mycell In myRange
        If resultStr <> "" And firstCell Then resultStr = resultStr & ", "
        If firstCell Then
            nextLineStr = "[" & mycell.Value & ", "
            firstCell = False
        Else
            nextLineStr = nextLineStr & mycell.Value & "]"
            firstCell = True
            resultStr = resultStr & nextLineStr
        End If
    Next mycell
    create_matrix_format = resultStr
End Function
```

and call this function in a cell:
e.g. D5: =create_matrix_format(A2:B4)

[image: screenshot matrix format]

Answer (score 1):

Formula-based alternative:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,"["&A2:A4&", "&B2:B4&"]")
```